# Is it any good to use binary arithmetic in a C++ code like "C style"?

Tags: c++, c, coding-style, binary

I like the fact that the C language lets you use binary arithmetic in an explicit way in your code, sometimes the use of the binary arithmetic can also give you a little edge in terms of performance; but since I started studying C++ i can't really tell how much i have seen the explicit use of something like that in a C++ code, something like a pointer to pointer structure or an instruction for jumping to a specific index value through the binary arithmetic.

Is the binary arithmetic still important and relevant in the C++ world?
How i can optimize my arithmetic and/or an access to a specific index?
What about the C++ and the way in which the bits are arranged according to the standard?

... or i have taken a look at the wrong coding conventions ... ?

Comment: going to binary arithmetic is a micro optimization and (often) needlessly complicates code, go for readable code and let the compiler optimize it as it sees fit

Comment: ..and before you consider micro-optimizing,  can you prove that this is the slowest part of your code?

Comment: Use binary arithmetic *for what*, exactly? Can you be more specific? C++ includes all the same arithmetic operators that C has, and it's fine to use them. However, C++ gives you a lot of tools that let you work at a higher level than C. So, please provide some examples of the kinds of things you're talking about.

Comment: @Caleb for example the shift operator `<<` or `>>`, which is a quick way to calculate "something times 2" or "something divided by 2"

Comment: Today, C compilers are smart enough to optimize a*2 into a<<1 where appropriate.  There's no need to refer to that as "the C style" - that is really more "the low-level assembly coder from the 1980s writing C" style. (Also, these days, `mul` is generally just as fast as `shl`, and in some cases could be *faster*. Don't try to out-optimize the compiler based on possibly-antiquated knowledge.)

Comment: @user827992: Using the shift operators to multiply/divide by 2 is **not** quicker in either language. micro optimization like this are already done by the compiler and it does a much better job at it than you can. The only thing you can do is screw up the ability of the compiler to see an optimization so concentrate on writting clean code and doing things the compiler can't do (design good code).

Answer (score 25, accepted):

In short: **No, it is not any good to use "binary arithmetic"(in sense the question asks it) or "C style" in C++**.

What makes you believe bitwise arithmetic would be any faster really? You can throw your bitwise operations all over the code, but what would make it any faster?

The thing is, almost whatever *trivial* thing you're trying to solve, can be solved easier by the standard high-level features(including the standard library, STL and STL algorithms). In some specific cases you might indeed want to switch the individual bits, for example when working with *bitmasks*. Or storing very compact data, for example when writing a compression algorithm, a dense file format or working for example with embedded systems.

If you are concerned with performance, *always* write a simple and trivial algorithm first. Just make it work. Then, measure the time your algorithm takes with typical input. Now, if you at this point feel that it is too slow, only then you can **try** optimizing it by hand with these "bitwise arithmetic" tricks. And after done, **measure** if your code is any faster. The chances are that it is not, unless you really know what you are doing in that specific situation/case.

Frankly, the best way to understand about this kind of low-level constructs which deal with performance is to study assembly language. It really makes you realize that no, writing some bit-manipulating wizzcode is not any faster than using that `sort(begin(v),end(v))`. Just because you operate at low level doesn't mean you operate fast. In general, **Algorithms are more important than implementation details!**

Basically whatever the "*C style*" means, **please**, stay away from it when writing C++. They are two completely different languages. Don't mix them.

Bjarne Stroustrup gave a great talk about C++ style in Microsoft's GoingNative 2012 conference this February, please take a look: http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/GoingNative-2012/Keynote-Bjarne-Stroustrup-Cpp11-Style

Especially the parts between around 10 and 15 minutes are great, when he talks about old C-style code compared to modern C++ style.

Comment: "Algorithms > implementation details" - rubbish! Equally important. Watch this: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aMnn0Jq0J-E

Comment: Yes, (mostly) rubbish. Some algorithms and data structures (radix sort, tries, etc.) are efficient *because* they exploit binary representation.

Comment: @James Of course, you can twist the statemet to not hold true in *specific* cases, for example for given input size N optimized merge sort can be faster than non-optimized quicksort and if you always keep your input under/at most N, it's no use to use that unoptimal implementation ofquicksort because your fast merge sort outperforms it in **your** typical usage scenarios. The trick is to pick the most optimal algorithm + implementation available for the certain input size. This process begins with picking the most efficiet algorithm first, then the most efficient implementation.

Comment: @zvrba I am definitely **not** suggesting that low-level bitwise trickery doesn't matter or that it shouldn't be exploited where it can. What I am saying is that I believe that *in most cases* there is actually no need to go "low-level". The same can be achieved by staying high, and using what the language gives you. For example, don't write your ultra-optimized inline-asm Quicksort, because the STL algorithm sort() is, *with high probability*, way faster. The bottom line is to first rely on what's available(e.g. standard library) and only then rely on tailored special-purpose low-level stuff.

Comment: @zxcdw: While algorithms can be efficient on paper the physical characteristics of what executes that algorithm can make a lot of difference.

Comment: @James Sure, it's true that *in the end*, it is the **implementation** which dictates the absolute performance. However, clever algorithm always beats clever implementation in general case. For clarity, simply put, given big enough input size, O(n log n) algorithm running on a wrist watch eventually outperforms O(n^2) algorithm running on the fastest computer ever built. Implementation details are irrelevant, asymptotic running time matters more with big input sizes - those which take time to execute and as such need fast running time. As such, never underestimate either. :)

Comment: @zxcdw The myth of asymptotic running time and "big inputs". O(n^2) algorithm may have low enough constant that it is faster than the best known O(n log n) if I know that my particular problem instance is limited to, say, n < 100. FWIW, I have managed to implement a quick sort that significantly outperforms std::sort on a large vector (whole contents of "Ana Karenina") of strings.

Comment: @zvrba It is true that the constant matters(sometimes alot!), and I do agree that you should not forget about the importance of the efficient implementation, however, I strongly think that you care about implementation efficiency *only* after you are certain that you have the optimal algorithm for the task at hand. If at that point performance is an issue, optimize. In general, leave optimization as the last resort, not the first(might be unnecessary, buggy, wastes time, hard to maintain etc.). That's why I said algorithms > implementation details, in general. There are exceptions of course.

Comment: @James: In the time it takes you to write your micro optimization the hardware your software is targeting will be more than that much faster.

Comment: @mattnz: Not true in the general case. I don't think the hardware for the Mars rovers is getting any faster out there on Mars.

Comment: Oh, and -1... you are confusing "bitwise" with "binary". I will argue to the death for binary arithmetic on machines that have binary state, otherwise your addition operators would be painfully slow (such as if they were implemented in base-10 arithmetic).

Comment: @ThomasEding I edited the answer to reflect your comment. Hopefully it's more accurate now.

Comment: @Thomas Eding: Just another example of using one specific case to try and prove the collective knowledge of best practitioners is wrong.

Answer (score 15):

> for example the shift operator << or >>, which is a quick way to
>   calculate "something times 2" or "something divided by 2"

Whether you're working in C or C++, write what you mean. Write `foo = foo * 2;` or `foo *= 2;` if that's what you mean, not `foo = foo << 1;`. Let the compiler take care of finding the fastest instruction to use and don't confuse the people who have to read your code with unnecessary hand optimization.

Comment: This is great advice. One example would be taking a modulo power-of-two of value V. e.g. `V%32`. The compiler will optimize it by using the *AND -1*-trick, doing `V&31`(only works for modulo power-of-two!). Also often times compiler can do lots of (perhaps non-obvious) tricks *even* during the compilation. For example multiplying a compile-time constant by another, the compiler can just compute the immediate value and replace the expression with that. This is called *constant folding*. The bottom line is that compiler often knows how to micro-optimize. ;)

Comment: @zxcdw: If one wants a proper modulus, and `V` might be negative, I would consider `V & 31` superior to any equivalent using `%`.  If C had a proper `mod` operator, I might regard `V mod 32` as being better yet, but no such feature exists.

Answer (score 9):

Follow these steps:

1. Write the code as simple and clear as possible.
2. Turn on all compiler optimizations.
3. Consider whether you have sufficient knowledge about the specific target CPU and its instruction set (assembler). If not, then you will probably have a hard time to do any manual optimizations and should probably not attempt it, as you will likely just end up obfuscating the code for no gain. Also note that manual optimization is only necessary if your compiler has poor support for the specific target platform. As an alternative, you could try another compiler.
4. Identify performance bottlenecks. How to find them depends on the target system. In "high-level" programs such as desktop programming, you benchmark your code through specific tools designed for that purpose, or through OS API functions. On "low-level" programs such as embedded systems, you typically use an oscilloscope to measure realtime performance. On any program, you can disassemble the code and see what the compiler actually came up with.
5. If there are no bottlenecks that affects your program's performance, you don't need to do a thing and you can stop reading here.
6. If there are bottlenecks that have impact on your program, you may need to perform manual optimization.
7. How do manual optimizations depends on the target CPU, there is no universal trick. Common things to look for are: floating point arithmetic, alignment, integer sizes, division, branch prediction & instruction cache handling, use of needlessly complex library functions... and so on.

Comment: And don't forget to mention that this approach is valid for C or C++ or any other compiled language.

Answer (score 4):

It depends on what sort of C++ code you're writing. The lower you are the more relevant it becomes. The problem with these types of questions is that everyone can only rely on their own experience and so if someone has never had to do this sort of thing they can't see why someone else might need to do it.

Here's [Joel's 'Five Worlds' article](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/FiveWorlds.html)

Answer (score 2):

I make use of binary arithmetic in virtually ALL computer languages I've programmed with. For example, take the addition operator `+`:

```
int sum = x + y; // compiler probably implements this as binary arithmetic!
```

I would find it hard to program in a language that did not support arithmetic, and I would find it hard to believe that arithmetic operations were not implemented by your compiler/interpreter using binary arithmetic (such as using base-10 arithmetic).

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic#Arithmetic_operations

http://www.binarymath.info/

http://www.swarthmore.edu/NatSci/echeeve1/Ref/BinaryMath/BinaryMath.html

TL;DR: Use the right terminology (bitwise ≠ binary), else you get pendatic answers like this.

Answer (score 1):

Binary arithmetic is bound to the implementation. You must be careful about implementation details such as endianness. Therefore, using binary operators isn't automatically faster than using elementary operators. Often, the compiler will perform more relevant optimizations, and a natural code can be better for performance as well as easier to read for both the compiler and the programmer.

Of course, there are some cases (such as Base64 encoding), where you must use those operators. But optimizing code with binary operators should be the last optimization, coming after perfecting your algorithms. For personal programming, some pretty tricks ([like this](http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html)) may be faster, but with serious programming, readability should come first.

And, like *zxcdw* said, C and C++ are both very different languages. C++ has more high-level libraries, so binary tricks are less famous.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no use of binary arithmetic in C++, except one "tiny" detail: the C++ standard *defines* the language semantics in terms of a *binary* abstract virtual machine that must use either 1st complement, 2nd complement or sign-magnitude integer representation.

Answer (score 1):

As many have mentioned already, be aware — **do not to prematurely optimize** things. But **when you find CPU-bound code that is a bottle neck**, one of the best ways to understand which of your alternate implementations would be better, using Clang C/C++ -> LLVM IR is a great idea. If you're more comfortable in a web browser, try http://llvm.org/demo/.

The IR (Intermediate Representation) generated by Clang and LLVM are virtual machine instructions. You can for instance write the same algorithm/arithmetic function in "C style" and "C++ style" (I'm guessing "STL-style"?) and compare the IR generated by the compiler. Even if your end-product compiler isn't based on LLVM, the IR code will be representative of what code is *actually* generated and compiled. Beyond IR there is only hardware optimizations (like how landing pads from conditional branches are implemented). LLVM can produce target machine assembly, if you think it would make you wiser (but I wouldn't recommend going beyond IR).

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes several flags are crammed into a single byte to save space. Sometimes it's premature, other times critical.

Microsoft SQL Server will store multiple columns of data type "bit" in the same byte. In this case it's not a premature optimization. You save 2 to 8 times the disk space, for 2 to 8 bit columns (this is a big deal). You get faster searches as well (very big deal). It's also more likely you will be able to cache a set of data in memory. This is perfect. Since there is no benefit in indexing binary data, you might as well pack the bits together. And the bitwise nature is not exposed to client programmers so everyone is happy.

The windows API crams several options per byte. You manipulate the display options with bitwise operations. I would say this one was premature. It also made many people give up on windows programming. But the programmers who wrote the API came from the old days when space was severely limited. At the time it may have been a good idea to design an API around bitwise manipulation.

Client/server video games love to pack multiple flags in a byte. For example, on the server the game calculates your damage. It will send back the display data to the client, with several flags like if it was a critical hit, if it killed the enemy, etc. The display would then process with bitwise operations.  This is debatable whether it's premature or not. But I would lean towards saying less is more when pushing data over a network.